# Advertising European PhD opportunities for students in China

Tags: phd, computer-science, france, china

We have got interesting funding opportunities for Chinese students interested in doing a PhD in France.

A good match would be familiar with proof/type theory and functional programming.

However, we are not sure what would the best venue be to advertise this kind of opportunities.

Are there some appropiate mailing lists or forums? Are there chinese haskell/ocaml user groups?

Comment: You could always email a description of the opportunity to the careers department in some Chinese universities and have them distribute it among the students.

Comment: Advertising in Chinese should boost your outreach